# Post edits from QGIS to Open Street Map database

Tags: qgis

How can I post edits from QGIS to Open Street Map database?

Similar to JSOM interface which can extract the data form Open Street Map then edit the data and post the edits back to Open Street map.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I had download the data in QGIS by using OpenLayers plugin and Vector ‣ OpenStreetMap ‣ Downlod data. I have done my editing in QGIS. I want to post the data back to OpenStreetMap Database.